# Redux Toolkit in TypeScript: createAction abstraction of adding timestamp

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Using [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) with TypeScript, I want to be able to add a `timestamp` property to all payloads using a [prepare callback](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAction#using-prepare-callbacks-to-customize-action-contents) on `createAction()` and maintain good type definitions. Currently I do this with a lot of repeated code like:

```js
const timestampAdder = (unpreparedPayload) => {
    const prepared = { payload: unpreparedPayload };
    if (!unpreparedPayload.timestamp) {
        prepared.payload.timestamp = Date.now();
    }
    return prepared;
};

export const someActionCreator = createAction(
  'slice_name/action_name',
  (
    prePayload: Omit<MyPayloadInterface, 'timestamp'>
  ): { payload: MyPayloadInterface; } => timestampAdder(prePayload)
);

export const someActionCreator2 = createAction(
  'slice_name/action2_name',
  (
    prePayload: Omit<EntirelyDifferentInterface, 'timestamp'>
  ): { payload: EntirelyDifferentInterface; } => timestampAdder(prePayload)
);

// ...repeat the same structure for each action I want to add "timestamp" to...
```

If this was plain JS (or less strict TS) I could do something like:

```js
export const jsActionCreator1 = createAction('js/action_name1', timestampAdder);
export const jsActionCreator2 = createAction('js/action_name2', timestampAdder);
```

But because the interfaces for the various action creators in TS are different, I end up writing a lot of boilerplate for each to maintain good types. I could do the same in TS:

```js
export const myActionCreator = createAction('slice_name/action3_name', timestampAdder);
```

But then I lose the benefit of types, and I can invoke the action creator with `any` argument:

```js
myActionCreator(123);
myActionCreator('abc');
myActionCreator({ a: 1, b: 'c' });
```

Is there a good way to reduce boilerplate but maintain good types? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do something like

```
const timestampAdder = <T>() => (unpreparedPayload: T) => {
    const payload = Object.assign( { timestamp: Date.now() }, unpreparedPayload )
    return { payload };
};
```

and use it like

```
export const actionCreator1 = createAction('js/action_name1', timestampAdder<{foo: string}>());
export const actionCreator2 = createAction('js/action_name2', timestampAdder<{bar: number}>());
```

Essentially, you have one method call wrapped around, just to "bind" the type there.

Comment: I think this needs `unpreparedPayload: Omit<T, 'timestamp'>` since `timestamp` shouldn't exist on the pre-processed payload. Otherwise `actionCreator1(myPayload)` must have `myPayload.timestamp`. Unfortunately, the type I want to pass is a union, like `timestampAdder<MyUnionType>()`, and now I get `Argument of type '{ p1: string; p2: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Omit<MyUnionType, "timestamp">'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'p2' does not exist in type 'Omit<MyUnionType, "timestamp">'.ts(2345)`. In this case, `p2` only exists on half of the union.

Comment: It shouldn't, `Object.assign` adds that type to T. See [this TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwMZQKYEMaoIJJsCAOwF84AzKCEOAcgAE0ATAVwA8ArAZwHoYIIANgGtgMGgChxSIp3j4QqWenDZGjVFDgBeOAB4AKnFSsshRp0TEAfAAoAlNqtwbzQmDRh0TAAroAngIQ6IwAXHD6DlpOCOJwcXDShLJwngFBjNpwAPIARuyoeAB06JycwADmhDaIcPKKMMpgYQAimKiFhBAA7vZwxAA0cK7uqJ4+-oHBcHax8WgwzFCENamTGcQA3OKbklIycvWq6po6dUoqahq6COT8YbJQwITlfbYze0kHsrj4RFooGCwPwIVQARGR+KDBlhvpcoO9uNxagALYAWLrQIScD7JVhhQjMEA5DSZGEwYFEGwICEQMKggBCXlBxDshVW6UKZwa4CAA)

Comment: Thanks so much! What you have here is `T` being the type _without_ `timestamp: number;` included, where I was passing in _with_ it included. Since the actions will want _without_ `timestamp` and the reducers will want _with_, I'll need to write a little extra code to split each of my payload types, but it's much less code and so much more readable than what I have  been doing. Thanks again! I'm marking this the accepted answer, but it might make sense to clarify in the body that `T` is without `timestamp` and the type used in the reducer is with it.

Comment: Yes, T is without timestamp, and that was very deliberately so - I might have misunderstood your question in the first place though ;)
I adjusted the example action type calls above to some more... valid ones ^^